# How does a command interpreter/Shell recognize a command?

Tags: operating-systems, interpreters

I want to know when we enter a command in a shell then how does the computer recognize that command?
Does it match that command with something already stored in files?

Comment: How in general do you go about getting insights? When turning to a community,  assume [there is guidance](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/asking). [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on?r=SearchResults&s=2|351.0732) offers help in picking a site.

Answer (score 1):

Text committed to be interpreted as a command is assumed to be a phrase (to avoid any term with a special meaning) in the *command language* of the system (here: `Shell` (and "layers" beneath)) that shall assign meaning to it (and cause appropriate effects).
A command language is one instance of a [formal language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-languages).
Many command languages, including [shell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell) allow [programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming): their languages are [programming languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages).
Formal languages in general, programming languages, [interpreters](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpreters) and [compilers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilers) are notable topics of computer science as is [operating system principles](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems).